# Let $A$ be a square matrix, such that $A^3 = I$. If 1 is not an eigenvalue of $A$, show: $A^{2} + A + I = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So 1 is neither a eigenvalue of $A^2$ nor of $A^3$. But I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: $A(A^2+A+I) =$ what?

Comment: You can't say that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^3=I$ which clearly has eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $3$.

Comment: @MarkBennet I was thinking that if $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $a^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$, hence if $a \neq 1 \implies a^3 \neq 1$

Comment: @MarkBennet Huh? $A^3=I$ does not have any eigenvalues; it's not a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $0=A^3-I=(A-I)(A^2+A+I)$. Since $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ then $A-I$ is invertible and thus $A^2+A+I=0$.

Comment: dont you want to argue $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ implies that $A-I$ is invertible? $YX = 0$ for matrices and $Y\neq 0$ doesn't have to apply that $X =0$

Comment: @Olof you're right, edited.

Comment: Why does that imply that $A - I$ is invertible?

Comment: Because for square matrices, injective <=> invertible and by definition, if 1 is not an eigenvalue then $A-I$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Since an answer has been given, here is a hint of another way to proceed.

Let $B=A^2+A+I$ and for an arbitrary vector $x$ consider the vector $y=Bx$.

Comment: With $AB = A(A^2 + A + I) = A^3 + A^2 + A = A^2 + A +  I = B$. $Ay = ABx =  Bx = y$. The definition of an eigenvalue $k$ with eigenvector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus{0}$ is: $Ay = ky$. $Ay = y$ implies that the eigenvalue is $1$, which is false. Hence $y$ is not a eigenvector and must be $0$.

Comment: @MoccaRolp Indeed. And since $x$ was arbitrary and $Bx=y=0$ ... This technique of applying a transformation to an arbitrary element (here an arbitrary vector) is one worth noting, which is the main reason I put the hint in this way. To motivate this think: I want to prove that $B=0$. That must mean that $Bx=0$ for any vector $x$. How does that work out - let's give it a go and see.

Answer (score 0):

$t^3-1$ is anihilating polynomial for $A$. I assume that $A$ is complex matrix and $1$ is not an eigenvalue, so possible minimal polynomials will be any of the $t-\omega, t-\omega^2, (t-\omega)(t-\omega^2)$.

This gives $A=\omega.I, A=\omega^2. I$ or $(A-\omega)(A-\omega^2)$ as the possibility for $A$, each of which satisfy $A^2+A+I=0$.